# Set permission for a specific column in view for table format in drupal 8

Tags: views

I have created a view in table format and added a field as global custom text field. I want to show this field to administrator only, not to other created roles. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**you need to do something like this in global php field :**

```
$uid = 1; 
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid); 
$roles = $user->getRoles();
$v=$roles[1];
if($v == "administrator") 
{
echo "your-content"; 
 }
```

Global php field will be available as Replacement pattern add that variable in your custom text field.